# QGIS Simplifying polygons with keeping points inside of them

Tags: qgis, point, simplify, generalization

I'm creating a processing where I do calculations on address points inside of counties.

I need to generalise county polygons in order to make my processing faster.
How do I make sure that address points stay inside of their counties after shape simplification?

In example here if I simplify too much points from the red polygon will go to the yellow one.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try subdividing the polygons rather than simplifying them will help more

Comment: @IanTurton how can the user simplify polygons retaining topology rules (every point must stay inside it's polygon)?

Comment: @IanTurton could u elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the polygons is unlikely to help speed queries up by much as will be difficult to achieve with out moving any of the points.

You may get more speed up by applying [`st_subdivide`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html) on the polygons before carrying out the point in polygon tests as the spatial index will be more performant on many small polygons rather than a few big ones.